# Как выводит текстовые значения из таблицы используя Join в Mysql

Tags: python, mysql, sql

```
sql = "SELECT \
  user_id AS 'Покупатель', \
  item_id AS 'Товар' \
  FROM orders \
  INNER JOIN users ON users.id = orders.id \
  INNER JOIN items ON items.id = orders.id"
mycursor.execute(sql)
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
for x in myresult:
  print(x)
```

В данном случае оно выводит только лишь цифры, ну как и указано в коде, а желаемый результат был бы

John - Кепка красная

John - Кепка синяя

[image: таблица items]

[image: таблица users]

Ну и ордерс понятно,3 столбца id, user_id, item_id

Comment: `xxxx_id`, как следует из имени поля - числовой идентификатор. А вовсе даже не имя или название. Короче, просто не те поля выводишь, вот и всё.

Answer (score 0):

Выводит только цифры потому, что в SELECT выбираются id пользователя, заказа и товара.

В показанных на картинках таблицах нет таблицы orders, есть только users и items.

В таблицах users и items нет колонок

user_id
item_id

Есть только id в каждой

```
SELECT 
  a.login AS 'Покупатель', 
  b.title AS 'Товар'
  (здесь должна быть выборка items заказа, например c.items AS ‘Состав заказа’) 
  FROM a.users 
  INNER JOIN b.orders ON users.id = orders.id 
  INNER JOIN c.items ON items.id = orders.id
```